# CSS Framework with detailed documentation

Tags: css, css-frameworks

I started using Foundation 3 from Zurb yesterday but the documentation they have provided with the Framework is not that much detailed. Is there any other CSS Framework which comes with detailed documentation or has a book? Links or detailed tutorials would be awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Twitter bootstrap framework is very well documented, and has a good community behind it: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/